# My code for New-AzureRmWebAppSSLBinding is not being recognised in Azure Cloudshell

Tags: azure, ssl, binding

I am trying to add a new binding and received a link to the following guide from Microsoft:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.websites/new-azurermwebappsslbinding?view=azurermps-6.13.0

I have tried each iteration of the code to add a new binding but I have been unsuccessful receiving the error:

Get-AzureRmWebAppSSLBinding : Operation returned an invalid status code 'NotFound'

Example of code im using is

New-AzureRmWebAppSSLBinding -ResourceGroupName "productResourceGroup" -WebAppName "webApp-staging-product-productgroup-1" -Thumbprint "i4j3u3oiejrngjroeidjfnf443irujfnfuj34"-Name "staging-product.company.co.uk" -CertificateFilePath "C:\Documents\CJeans\Certificate" -CertificatePassword "password"

Answer (score 0):

Well the path `C:\Documents\CJeans\Certificate` most likely doesn't exist on CloudShell.

It doesn't use your local drive but mounted File Storage from Azure Storage Account. You need to upload certificate there.

Comment: I have also connected to Azure via Powershell App on my laptop and tried to run it there but still get the NotFound invalid status for the script

Comment: If you use multiple subscriptions you should also run `Select-AzureRmSubscription` to ensure you run script on the proper one.